# Two users / two sessions from one PC to one site at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xmlhttprequest

I spent hours, days .. researching and trying to write some code in VB.NET or C# that would allow me to connect two users/accounts from the same PC at the same time to one website. What I need to do is as follow:

User A -> thread1 -> proxyA -> website.com
User B -> thread2 -> proxyB -> website.com

So far I was able to write some code by using XMLHTTP60 but only one user can login (only one user can login at the time). After researching online it seems like it is not possible as XMLHTTP uses IE settings and comm protocol. Bottom line: can't make two sessions at the time.

Is there any way to accomplish that without running two instances of software?

Thank you....

Comment: Websites typically identify sessions via cookies.  So long as each of your contexts has a separate cookie, this should work.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use `WebClient` or `HttpClient`.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth: I wish I could manage to keep it separate. :(

SLaks: I've tried by using WebClient but was unable to keep login to the site. First I download whole website (HTML source); than captcha image and place it to the imagebox on my form so that user could type it in textbox. I do .UploadValues with all params; req. headers etc. However, I always get "incorrect captcha". That happens only when using WebClient. Can you point to decent HttpClient example so I wouldn't miss? Thank you....

Comment: @SLaks Thank you very much! It works with HttpClient; put that in an answer and I will accept it :) Now I am able with HttpClient to user proxy (separate for each user). Also I am able to have both users login to one site without proxy. It keeps sessions in separate containers. I'll need to read a bit more about it but so far (for testing purpose) it works!! Dude you rock!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use COM-based HTTP components.

Instead, use `HttpClient`, a modern, asynchronous, managed HTTP stack which will do everything you need.